# Installing IPython and Eclipse returns errors

Tags: eclipse, ipython

I have tried the following commands-

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But then I am facing errors about failing to fetch packages.

```
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-screenshot/gnome-screenshot_3.4.1-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/grub2/grub-pc_1.99-21ubuntu3.17_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you're connected to the internet. The commands you're using are not installation commands. `apt-get update` updates the Ubuntu repositories. This is useful if you want to install something from a PPA. `apt-get clean` removes unnecessary files from your computer, such as dependencies from uninstalled packages. `apt-get upgrade` upgrades your currently installed software to the latest version in the repos.

To actually install IPython, make sure you're connected to the internet, and type into the terminal `sudo apt-get install ipython`. To install Eclipse, type in `sudo apt-get install eclipse`. I hope this helps you!

Comment: @ash111 You're welcome! Remember to choose a best answer, abhijeetmote's or mine.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can first of all see weather there is internet connection is available or not? 

`ping google.com`

see if its reachable or not?

to install ipython on linux you can try
`sudo apt-get install ipython`

for eclipse you need to download the software as per your system configuration depends on 32 bit or 64 bit.

You can Download Eclipse from the below link
https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/sr2